Short story about a decades-long mission to collect a soil/rock sample from a far away planet. There are multiple generations of astronaut children
I read a short story excerpt from a textbook in high school. I would love to continue the story.
The story starts with astronauts beginning a deep space mission to collect a soil sample. I remember one of the astronauts becoming mentally unwell and the other astronauts had to kill him. Some of the other astronauts go on to have kids. I don’t remember which generation it was, but eventually the children of the original astronauts lose interest in learning- believing that it is a waste of time. This generation finally makes it back to Earth but end up being made fun of because they are not as smart as everyone else. The mission seems to have been pointless and no one on Earth really cares about the mission or that this new generation of astronauts has landed on Earth.
This was about 10 years ago, so I don’t remember too many details
